# PHP: include function doesn't work

Tags: php, html, include

I've been out of the web world for a little while, but I'm trying to make a website using HTML5 and PHP. It's a simple html file with a PHP include statement linking to PHP file. This is basically my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>Title</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
                  <?php include("header.php"); ?>
                  TEST
     </body>
     </html>
     </html>
```

And to keep it simple, let's say header.php just has the following:

```
 <div class="header">
     Hello
 </div>
```

So the text in index.html will show up but nothing from header.php. I have PHP5 downloaded, so I don't understand what the problem is. Are there some configuration settings that need to be set before trying to load this local file? Is it something with HTML5? All my PHP projects from college don't load either and they used to locally. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: What does the HTML source code view of the page show?

Comment: How are you opening that page?

Comment: What does `error_reporting(E_ALL)` tells you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does this php code not execute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736141/why-does-this-php-code-not-execute)

Comment: @Pekka: The source code view prints out verbatim what is written in the index file. So it prints out <?php include("header.php"); ?>.

Comment: @deceze: I'm opening the index file in google chrome, firefox, and ie9. None will show my header file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is basically my index.html file:

Your file needs to have `.php` extension not `.html` unless otherwise specified via settings to serve `.html` as a php file.

Comment: I've tried changing the index file extension to .php, like you suggest, but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Should not matter, because the called file is important, not the included.

Comment: @Katie: How are you running the file? Do you have WAMP or other server installed? Are you accessing file using `http://localhost/....`. Is `header.php` present in same folder where your script is and that you are not making any spelling mistakes. That should work otherwise.

Comment: I've been accessing it by file:///. I just tried http://localhost/ and nothing shows up now. Ah! I don't have a server installed.

Comment: @Katie: That's the issue then :)

Comment: After installing, are there any special instructions? I installed WAMP and reloaded my file using localhost, and no text, not even from my index file shows up.

Comment: @Katie: You need to learn some basics, search for the documentation of WAMP, it should help you.

Answer (score 1):

As Sarfraz said you need to save the file as .php not .html, that should work.

I assume you have installed Apache or some webserver along with PHP. If not, better use XAMPP or WAMP.

And do run it as `http://localhost/index.php` after saving it default web server directory (www, htaaccess, etc.).